# USB stick no longer opens with Nautilus (Polo File Manager)

Tags: nautilus, usb-drive

I am running a new install of Ubuntu 18.10 on Wayland. I recently installed the Polo file manager and it has made itself the default file manager. However I prefer Nautilus to be the default when I plug in a USB-Stick.

How can I make Nautilus the default application for my USB-sticks again?

Comment: Installing a different file manager and making it the default IS certainly the reason for the unwanted behavior.

Comment: I haven't made Polo the default file manager. I just installed it to see if I like it. Maybe it made itself the default, and if this is the case how do I make nautilus the default again?

Comment: Please **do not** add 'solved' to the title, it's not how it is done here. Accepting an answer is the only way to mark a question as "*solved*" (in case of your self-answer you need to wait for 2 days before you'll be able to accept the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the Polo file manager and that is also the solution. In the Polo file manager, I went to `Setup` and then `General` and then you can choose under`File Manager` either Files, Polo or Disc Usage Analyser.

Sorry for posting such a question but I was genuinely puzzled and would still like to know if there is a relatively simple way to set the default file manager in Ubuntu.